# C# Convert Image To COMPLETE Black&White

Tags: c#, image-processing, gif, screen-capture

I have a gif image which is way too big for my needs (even if it is 100~300kb)

In photoshop, I managed to turn my 160kb gif to 15kb (1/10 of his size!!) simply by reducing the number of colors he is using to 2 (Black&White).

I wanted to do the same thing in my application but all I could find was turning image into grayscale which turned my 160kb gif to 100kb.

Is there anyway to turn my gif to COMPLETE black and white? Any other way that can shrink the gif to an even smaller size will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [codeproject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/BitonalImageConverter.aspx) of how to turn it into a bitonal G4 compressed TIFF. Note that this is excellent for images with a lot of whitespace and text, but not so good for images. With images, you may want to see the other answer and use dithering.

Comment: I havfe an image and it turned my 160kb to 9kb. Understandable. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There is some code here on SO: [Bayer Ordered Dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441388/bayer-ordered-dithering) that is supposed to do that I think (not tested). Worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Converting Image to Black and White in C#](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Converting-Image-to-Black-and-White-in-C.aspx)

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2010 <a href="http://www.gutgames.com">James Craig</a>

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.*/

#region Usings
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
#endregion

 namespace Utilities.Media.Image
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class for setting up and applying a color matrix
     /// </summary>
     public class ColorMatrix
    {
         #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
         /// </summary>
         public ColorMatrix()
         {
       }

         #endregion

           #region Properties

         /// <summary>
         /// Matrix containing the values of the ColorMatrix
         /// </summary>
         public float[][] Matrix { get; set; }

         #endregion

         #region Public Functions

         /// <summary>
         /// Applies the color matrix
         /// </summary>
         /// <param name="OriginalImage">Image sent in</param>
         /// <returns>An image with the color matrix applied</returns>
        public Bitmap Apply(Bitmap OriginalImage)
         {
             using (Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap))
             {
                 System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(Matrix);
                 using (ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                     Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
                     NewGraphics.DrawImage(OriginalImage,
                         new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height),
                         0, 0, OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height,
                         GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                         Attributes);
                 }
             }
             return NewBitmap;
         }

         #endregion
     }
 }


 /// <summary>
/// Converts an image to black and white
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Image">Image to change</param>
/// <returns>A bitmap object of the black and white image</returns>
public static Bitmap ConvertBlackAndWhite(Bitmap Image)
{
     ColorMatrix TempMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    TempMatrix.Matrix = new float[][]{
                     new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
                     new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                };
     return TempMatrix.Apply(Image);
}

 float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={ 
         new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
        new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
         new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} 
     };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this. Either run it via command line by `Process.Start`, or use the COM interface which is part of the Windows installation.  The option "-monochrome" is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Floyd-Steinberg dithering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering

Alternatively, if you don't need dithering, find the average luminosity and turn all pixels above that to white and below that to black.

Answer (score -1):

Working version of the solution posted by Chuck Conway

```
 /*
Copyright (c) 2010 <a href="http://www.gutgames.com">James Craig</a>

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.*/

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WebCamService {
    class ColorMatrix {

        public float[][] Matrix { get; set; }

        public Bitmap Apply(Bitmap OriginalImage) {
            using (Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(OriginalImage)) {
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(Matrix);
                using (ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes()) {
                    Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
                    NewGraphics.DrawImage(OriginalImage,
                        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height),
                        0, 0, OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                        Attributes);
                }
            }
            return OriginalImage;
        }

        public static Bitmap ConvertBlackAndWhite(Bitmap Image) {
            ColorMatrix TempMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
            TempMatrix.Matrix = new float[][]{
                     new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
                     new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                };
            return TempMatrix.Apply(Image);
        }


    }
}
```